# WCF .net streaming in chunks method calls slows down

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, upload

I have a client-server WCF uploader/downloader.

It downloads/uploads files in an infinite loop (gets list of files and uploads/downloads them until someone stops it).

The client is created like this:

```
ChannelFactory<IContract> scf = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(
    this._endPoint.Binding, this._endPoint.AddressFull);

this.Channel = scf.CreateChannel();
this.channelFactory = scf;
```

and its binding is TCP client/server and is created like this:

```
public static CustomBinding GetCustomTcpBinding(TransferMode mode, long MaxBufferBufferPoolSize,  long MaxReceivedMessageSize, int MaxBufferSize, TimeoutHelper Timeouts, StreamerType st)
{
    MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement binaryEncoding = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement();

    System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas rq = binaryEncoding.ReaderQuotas;

    SetReaderQuotas(ref rq, int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue,  int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);

    TcpTransportBindingElement tcpTransport = new TcpTransportBindingElement();

    tcpTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;// MaxReceivedMessageSize;
    tcpTransport.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;// MaxBufferSize;
    tcpTransport.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;// MaxBufferBufferPoolSize;
    tcpTransport.TransferMode = mode;

    switch(st)
    {
        case StreamerType.Client:
        {
            //tcpTransport.ConnectionBufferSize = Consts.TCP_CLIENT_CONNECTION_BUFFER_SIZE;
            break;
        }
        case StreamerType.Server:
        {
            tcpTransport.ConnectionBufferSize = Consts.TCP_SERVER_CONNECTION_BUFFER_SIZE;
            tcpTransport.MaxOutputDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            break;
        }
    }        

    BindingElementCollection elements = new BindingElementCollection();

    elements.Add(binaryEncoding);
    elements.Add(tcpTransport);

    CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(elements)
    {
        Name = "TcpUserNameBinding"
    };

    binding.SetTimeouts(Timeouts);

    //binding.SetDefaultQuotas();

    return binding;
}
```

and:

```
 long MaxBufferBufferPoolSize = 65536 * 4;
 long MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
 int MaxBufferSize = 65536;
```

server is:

```
 long MaxBufferBufferPoolSize = 65536 * 4;
 long MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
 int MaxBufferSize = 65536;
```

The download/upload is streamed in chunks, stream on each read checks if each chunk size is exceeded and allows to get more or ends.

Each chunk is about 2MB, after that next call is made.

Caller method from client looks like:

```
public void Call(Action<IContract> action)
{
    var channel = this.Channel;

    if (channel == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    action(channel);
    return;           
}
```

The problem is that some calls are slower, some faster, and I cannot predict what can cause the problem.

To download I use:

```
using (fs = new Streamer.Common.StreamWithProgress(fsTemp = new   FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, fileName), System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
{
    fs.Position = position;

    var res = ClientConn.SafeCall(a => a.UploadFile(new Streamer.Common.RemoteFileInfo() { FileName = fileName, Length = length, Position = position, FileByteStream = fs }), true, position == 0);

    position = res.Position;
    hasNextChunk = res.HasNextChunk;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a [streamed binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx)?

Comment: It uses streamed binding.

Comment: Then you don't need these huge buffers. In streamed bindings, buffers are only used to read the message headers. Try to set the max buffer size to a reasonable size, and get rid of the buffer pool entirely. Also, why are you using MTOM instead of the binary encoder? (You could just use a plain streamed `NetTcpBinding` for this). And maybe I'm pushing it too far, but why the chunking if you use a streamed transport?

Comment: I changed MTOM to binary, and it looks better, but problem is that each call to download/upload can hang up to some seconds, and thats whats puzzling me

Comment: You should try to profile your code (both the client and server). That way you'll know where exactly it freezes. Also, do you handle concurrent connections?

Comment: Its set up locally on my machine, and only one connection is made, hovewer:InstanceContextMode = PerSession and ConcurrencyMode = multiple

Comment: Unless you actually need the session, try `PerCall` instead. Then, like I said, you'll have to use a profiler...